# Что за условные конструкции в html {% if...%}?

Tags: html

В фигурных скобках с процентами.

Например:

```
{% if description %}
<meta name="description" content="{{ description }}"/>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Это не html, а вероятно Django-шаблон

Comment: Возможно, это opencart или wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это синтаксис какого-либо шаблонизатора. Какого именно - трудно сказать, потому что их множество. Может быть [Django](https://djbook.ru/ch04s03.html), а может быть [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/), а может ещё что-либо.

Основная цель использования шаблонизаторов — это отделение представления данных от исполняемого кода (типа не смешивать основной язык программирования и разметку). Поэтому бывает так, что код пишется на сервере, формируются переменные, которые отсылаются на клиент с шаблоном, а там уже на синтаскисе шаблонизатора оформляется код